# How do I use a default namespace in an lxml xpath query?

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

I have an xml document in the following format:

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:openSearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/" xmlns:gsa="http://schemas.google.com/gsa/2007">
  ...
  <entry>
    <id>https://ip.ad.dr.ess:8000/feeds/diagnostics/smb://ip.ad.dr.ess/path/to/file</id>
    <updated>2011-11-07T21:32:39.795Z</updated>
    <app:edited xmlns:app="http://purl.org/atom/app#">2011-11-07T21:32:39.795Z</app:edited>
    <link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://ip.ad.dr.ess:8000/feeds/diagnostics"/>
    <link rel="edit" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://ip.ad.dr.ess:8000/feeds/diagnostics"/>
    <gsa:content name="entryID">smb://ip.ad.dr.ess/path/to/directory</gsa:content>
    <gsa:content name="numCrawledURLs">7</gsa:content>
    <gsa:content name="numExcludedURLs">0</gsa:content>
    <gsa:content name="type">DirectoryContentData</gsa:content>
    <gsa:content name="numRetrievalErrors">0</gsa:content>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    ...
  </entry>
  ...
</feed>
```

I need to retrieve all `entry` elements using xpath in lxml.  My problem is that I can't figure out how to use an empty namespace.  I have tried the following examples, but none work.  Please advise.

```
import lxml.etree as et

tree=et.fromstring(xml)
```

The various things I have tried are:

```
for node in tree.xpath('//entry'):
```

or

```
namespaces = {None:"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" ,"openSearch":"http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/" ,"gsa":"http://schemas.google.com/gsa/2007"}

for node in tree.xpath('//entry', namespaces=ns):
```

or

```
for node in tree.xpath('//\"{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}entry\"'):
```

At this point I just don't know what to try.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It really feels weird that it won't let you find tags in the default namespace that wasn't not assigned a name. I couldn't believe my eyes when I've encountered this.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
import lxml.etree as et

ns = {"atom": "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"}
tree = et.fromstring(xml)
for node in tree.xpath('//atom:entry', namespaces=ns):
    print node
```

See also http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#namespaces-and-prefixes.

Alternative:

```
for node in tree.xpath("//*[local-name() = 'entry']"):
    print node
```

Comment: so there is no way to use a default namespace here?  I ask because it makes it easier to use the actual tag as it appears in the document, which is `<entry>`, rather than `<atom:entry>`

Comment: It's important to note that `tree.xpath("atom:entry")` doesn't work while in the non-namespaced document `tree.xpath("atom:entry")` does work. You need the `//` as in `tree.xpath("//atom:entry")`.

Comment: The `local-name` tip is a good one, for finding non-namespaced elements among namespaced ones.

Answer (score 2):

Use [findall](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.findall) method.

```
for item in tree.findall('{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}entry'): 
    print item
```

Comment: This is a useful work around, but is it possible to use namespaces in an actual xpath expression, using `tree.xpath()`