# Why isn't XMLFeedSpider failing to iterate through the designated nodes?

Tags: python, xml, rss, scrapy

I'm trying to parse through [PLoS](http://www.plos.org)'s RSS feed to pick up new publications.  The RSS feed is located [here](http://www.plosone.org/article/feed/search?unformattedQuery=*%3A*&sort=Date%2C+newest+first).

Below is my spider:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import XMLFeedSpider


class PLoSSpider(XMLFeedSpider):
    name = "plos"
    itertag = 'entry'
    allowed_domains = ["plosone.org"]
    start_urls = [
         ('http://www.plosone.org/article/feed/search'
          '?unformattedQuery=*%3A*&sort=Date%2C+newest+first')
    ]

    def parse_node(self, response, node):
        pass
```

This configuration produces the following log output (note the exception):

```
$ scrapy crawl plos
2015-02-06 00:19:08+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.24.4 started (bot: plos)
2015-02-06 00:19:08+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11, boto
2015-02-06 00:19:08+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'plos.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['plos.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'plos'}
2015-02-06 00:19:08+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2015-02-06 00:19:08+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2015-02-06 00:19:08+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2015-02-06 00:19:08+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: 
2015-02-06 00:19:08+0100 [plos] INFO: Spider opened
2015-02-06 00:19:08+0100 [plos] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-02-06 00:19:08+0100 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2015-02-06 00:19:08+0100 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 127.0.0.1:6080
2015-02-06 00:19:09+0100 [plos] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.plosone.org/article/feed/search?unformattedQuery=*%3A*&sort=Date%2C+newest+first> (referer: None)
2015-02-06 00:19:09+0100 [plos] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://www.plosone.org/article/feed/search?unformattedQuery=*%3A*&sort=Date%2C+newest+first>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 824, in runUntilCurrent
        call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/task.py", line 638, in _tick
        taskObj._oneWorkUnit()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/task.py", line 484, in _oneWorkUnit
        result = next(self._iterator)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 57, in <genexpr>
        work = (callable(elem, *args, **named) for elem in iterable)
    --- <exception caught here> ---
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 96, in iter_errback
        yield next(it)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/contrib/spidermiddleware/offsite.py", line 26, in process_spider_output
        for x in result:
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/contrib/spidermiddleware/referer.py", line 22, in <genexpr>
        return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/contrib/spidermiddleware/urllength.py", line 33, in <genexpr>
        return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/contrib/spidermiddleware/depth.py", line 50, in <genexpr>
        return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/contrib/spiders/feed.py", line 61, in parse_nodes
        for selector in nodes:
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/contrib/spiders/feed.py", line 87, in _iternodes
        for node in xmliter(response, self.itertag):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/iterators.py", line 31, in xmliter
        yield Selector(text=nodetext, type='xml').xpath('//' + nodename)[0]
    exceptions.IndexError: list index out of range
    
2015-02-06 00:19:09+0100 [plos] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2015-02-06 00:19:09+0100 [plos] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
    {'downloader/request_bytes': 282,
     'downloader/request_count': 1,
     'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
     'downloader/response_bytes': 7590,
     'downloader/response_count': 1,
     'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
     'finish_reason': 'finished',
     'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 5, 23, 19, 9, 379574),
     'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
     'log_count/ERROR': 1,
     'log_count/INFO': 7,
     'response_received_count': 1,
     'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
     'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
     'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
     'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
     'spider_exceptions/IndexError': 1,
     'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 5, 23, 19, 8, 834428)}
2015-02-06 00:19:09+0100 [plos] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Changing `itertag = "entry"` to `itertag = "//entry"` removes the exception, but no items are scraped.  I also tried using `scrapy.log.msg` to log a message from within `parse_node`, but nothing appears and no nodes are reported as having been scraped.

What am I doing wrong?

### Edit

Following alecxe's advice, here is a spider with namepaces defined.  The documentation is a bit skimpy so I'm still not sure why my logging calls aren't showing up...

```
from scrapy import log
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import XMLFeedSpider


class PLoSSpider(XMLFeedSpider):
    name = "plos"
    allowed_domains = ["plosone.org"]
    namespaces = [
        (
            'plos',
            ('http://www.plosone.org/article/feed/search'
             '?unformattedQuery=*%3A*&sort=Date%2C+newest+first')
        )
    ]
    itertag = 'plos:entry'

def parse_node(self, response, node):
    log.msg('*** PING ***')
```

And here is the output:

```
$ scrapy crawl plos
2015-02-06 18:33:01+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.24.4 started (bot: plos)
2015-02-06 18:33:01+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11, boto
2015-02-06 18:33:01+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'plos.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['plos.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'plos'}
2015-02-06 18:33:01+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2015-02-06 18:33:02+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2015-02-06 18:33:02+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2015-02-06 18:33:02+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: 
2015-02-06 18:33:02+0100 [plos] INFO: Spider opened
2015-02-06 18:33:02+0100 [plos] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-02-06 18:33:02+0100 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2015-02-06 18:33:02+0100 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 127.0.0.1:6080
2015-02-06 18:33:02+0100 [plos] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2015-02-06 18:33:02+0100 [plos] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
    {'finish_reason': 'finished',
     'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 6, 17, 33, 2, 65414),
     'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
     'log_count/INFO': 7,
     'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 6, 17, 33, 2, 60311)}
2015-02-06 18:33:02+0100 [plos] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

It should further be noted that running `scrapy shell "http://www.plosone.org/article/feed/search?unformattedQuery=*%3A*&sort=Date%2C+newest+first"` followed by `response.xpath('//entry')` produces an empty list (`[]`).  Yet, if you look at the raw XML data, you can see the `<entry>` tags plain as day.  I'm at a complete loss, here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *handle [namespaces](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=xmlfeedspider#scrapy.contrib.spiders.XMLFeedSpider.namespaces)*:

```
class PLoSSpider(XMLFeedSpider):
    name = "plos"

    namespaces = [('atom', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom')]
    itertag = 'atom:entry'
    iterator = 'xml'  # this is also important
```

See also:

- [how do I use empty namespaces in an lxml xpath query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053568/how-do-i-use-empty-namespaces-in-an-lxml-xpath-query)

Working example:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import XMLFeedSpider


class PLoSSpider(XMLFeedSpider):
    name = "plos"

    namespaces = [('atom', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom')]
    itertag = 'atom:entry'
    iterator = 'xml'

    allowed_domains = ["plosone.org"]
    start_urls = [
         ('http://www.plosone.org/article/feed/search'
          '?unformattedQuery=*%3A*&sort=Date%2C+newest+first')
    ]

    def parse_node(self, response, node):
        print node
```

Comment: Could you expand upon this, and possibly provide a working example?  I've tried modifying my code (please see edits), but I'm still not seeing any evidence that `parse_node` is being called...

Comment: @blz sure, updated the answer (note the importance of `iterator = 'xml'` - this is what I had missing in the initial answer, apologies).

Comment: Thanks for the updates!  Is there a particular reasoning behind your choice of a namespace?  Why 'atom' and its URL?

Comment: @blz the name is not really important, but the url is - I've taken it from the root xml node. Hope that helps and it is working on your end too.

Comment: It is indeed working!  Thanks!  One last question:  how is the URL important?  Is it documentation or is it actually *doing* something?  Thanks again!

Comment: @blz thanks, well, this is not really my topic, but [XML namespace (wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace) article should clear things up :)