# Python lxml - find tag block ammend

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, tags, lxml

I have the below xml which I have opened and parsed and I now need to find the specific product block with the territory 'IE' and then amend its 'cleared_for_sale' and 'wholesale_price_tier' values, but am unsure how to do it. Heres what doesnt work:

```
a = 0
territory = "IE"
for products22 in tree.xpath("//video/products/product"):
    node_video_temp = tree.xpath('//video/products/product')[a]
    if root.iterfind(node_video_temp, territory):
        ## Update the values ##
    a +=1
```

Heres the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://apple.com/itunes/importer" version="film5.0">
    <video>
        <products>
            <product>
                <territory>GB</territory>
                <cleared_for_sale>true</cleared_for_sale>
                <wholesale_price_tier>1</wholesale_price_tier>
            </product>
            <product>
                <territory>IE</territory>
                <cleared_for_sale>true</cleared_for_sale>
                <wholesale_price_tier>1</wholesale_price_tier>
            </product>
            <product>
                <territory>US</territory>
                <cleared_for_sale>true</cleared_for_sale>
                <wholesale_price_tier>1</wholesale_price_tier>
            </product>
        </products>
    </video>
</package>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an xpath expression to get all products where `territory` is `IE`:

```
//product[territory = "IE"]
```

But, you need to [handle an empty namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053568/how-do-i-use-empty-namespaces-in-an-lxml-xpath-query) here:

```
from lxml import etree

data = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://apple.com/itunes/importer" version="film5.0">
    <video>
        <products>
            <product>
                <territory>GB</territory>
                <cleared_for_sale>true</cleared_for_sale>
                <wholesale_price_tier>1</wholesale_price_tier>
            </product>
            <product>
                <territory>IE</territory>
                <cleared_for_sale>true</cleared_for_sale>
                <wholesale_price_tier>1</wholesale_price_tier>
            </product>
            <product>
                <territory>US</territory>
                <cleared_for_sale>true</cleared_for_sale>
                <wholesale_price_tier>1</wholesale_price_tier>
            </product>
        </products>
    </video>
</package>
"""

ns = {"x": "http://apple.com/itunes/importer"}
territory = 'IE'

root = etree.fromstring(data)
for product in root.xpath('//x:product[x:territory = "%s"]' % territory, namespaces=ns):
    print product.findtext('x:cleared_for_sale', namespaces=ns)
    print product.findtext('x:wholesale_price_tier', namespaces=ns)
```

Prints `cleared_for_sale` and `wholesale_price_tier` for territory="IE":

```
true
1
```

Comment: Instead of print product.findtext, how do I amend the values?

Comment: @speedyrazor do you mean changing the text value of an element?

Comment: Yes, so for example, change the wholesale_price_tier value to 7.

Comment: @speedyrazor should be `product.find('x:wholesale_price_tier').text = '7'`. Then, you would need to dump the tree to see the change.

Comment: sorry, have trouble now checking if wholesale_price_tier exists before updating it.