# Get rect tag from this XML file

Tags: python, xml, svg, xml-parsing, lxml

How do I get  from [this](http://pastebin.com/5Ka7SDUc) XML file using lxml library in Python?

I couldn't find the proper XPATH to get the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **handle [namespaces](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces)** (and an [empty one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053568/how-do-i-use-empty-namespaces-in-an-lxml-xpath-query) too):

```
namespaces = {
  "dc":"http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/",
  "cc": "http://creativecommons.org/ns#",
  "rdf": "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#",
  "svg": "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
  "myns": "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
}

tree = ET.fromstring(data)
for rect in tree.xpath("//myns:rect", namespaces=namespaces):
    print rect.attrib.get("id")
```

where `data` is an XML string you've provided.

For testing purposes it just prints `rect` element `id` attributes:

```
rect3347
rect3349
rect3351
rect3351-1
rect3351-17
rect3351-1-4
rect3397
rect3399
rect3401
rect3403
```