# Sorting XML tags by child elements Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, lxml, elementtree

I have a number of 'root' tags with children 'name'. I want to sort the 'root' blocks, ordered alphabetically by the 'name' element. Have tried lxml / etree / minidom but can't get it working...
I can't get it to parse the value inside the tags, and then sort the parent root tags.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
  <roots>
    <root>
      <path>//1.1.1.100/Alex</path>
      <name>Alex Space</name>
    </root>
    <root>
      <path>//1.1.1.101/Steve</path>
      <name>Steve Space</name>
    </root>
    <root>
      <path>//1.1.1.150/Bethany</path>
      <name>Bethanys</name>
    </root>
</roots>
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

    def sortchildrenby(parent, child):
        parent[:] = sorted(parent, key=lambda child: child)


tree = ET.parse('data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

sortchildrenby(root, 'name')
for child in root:
    sortchildrenby(child, 'name')


tree.write('output.xml')
```

Comment: So you want name to come first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to put the *name* nodes first:

```
x = """
  <roots>
    <root>
      <path>//1.1.1.100/Alex</path>
      <name>Alex Space</name>
    </root>
    <root>
      <path>//1.1.1.101/Steve</path>
          <name>Bethanys</name>
    </root>
    <root>
      <path>//1.1.1.150/Bethany</path>
        <name>Steve Space</name>
    </root>
</roots>"""

import lxml.etree as et
tree = et.fromstring(x)

for r in tree.iter("root"):
    r[:] = sorted(r, key=lambda ch: -(ch.tag == "name"))

print(et.tostring(tree).decode("utf-8"))
```

Which would give you:

```
<roots>
    <root>
      <name>Alex Space</name>
    <path>//1.1.1.100/Alex</path>
      </root>
    <root>
      <name>Bethanys</name>
    <path>//1.1.1.101/Steve</path>
          </root>
    <root>
      <name>Steve Space</name>
    <path>//1.1.1.150/Bethany</path>
        </root>
</roots>
```

But there is no need to sort if you just want to add them first, you can just remove and reinsert the name into index 0:

```
import lxml.etree as et
tree = et.fromstring(x)

for r in tree.iter("root"):
    ch = r.find("name")
    r.remove(ch)
    r.insert(0, ch)

print(et.tostring(tree).decode("utf-8"))
```

If the nodes are actually not in sorted order and you want to rearrange the *roots* node alphabetically:

```
x = """
  <roots>
    <root>
      <path>//1.1.1.100/Alex</path>
      <name>Alex Space</name>
    </root>
    <root>
      <path>//1.1.1.101/Steve</path>
         <name>Steve Space</name>
    </root>
    <root>
       <path>//1.1.1.150/Bethany</path>
       <name>Bethanys</name>
    </root>
</roots>"""
import lxml.etree as et
tree = et.fromstring(x)

tree[:] = sorted(tree, key=lambda ch: ch.xpath("name/text()"))

print(et.tostring(tree).decode("utf-8"))
```

Which would give you:

```
 <roots>
    <root>
      <path>//1.1.1.100/Alex</path>
      <name>Alex Space</name>
    </root>
    <root>
       <path>//1.1.1.150/Bethany</path>
       <name>Bethanys</name>
    </root>
    <root>
      <path>//1.1.1.101/Steve</path>
         <name>Steve Space</name>
    </root>
</roots>
```

You can also combine with either of the first two approach two also rearrange the *root* nodes putting name first.

Comment: Your final suggestion was what I was going for, thanks

Comment: No worries, I was not sure as your input already seemed sorted but I suppose that was actually your expected output for an unsorted file.

Comment: Use this answer if you're running into trouble because of namespaces, e.g. if the XPath expression doesn't find any elements: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8056239/412278
Otherwise, thanks a lot, @PadraicCunningham!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


xml="<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><roots><root><path>//1.1.1.100/Alex</path><name>Alex Space</name></root><root><path>//1.1.1.101/Steve</path><name>Steve Space</name></root><root><path>//1.1.1.150/Bethany</path><name>Bethanys</name></root></roots>"
oldxml = ET.fromstring(xml)

names = []
for rootobj in oldxml.findall('root'):
    names.append(rootobj.find('name').text)

newxml = ET.Element('roots')
for name in sorted(names):
    for rootobj in oldxml.findall('root'):
        if name == rootobj.find('name').text:
            newxml.append(rootobj)
ET.dump(oldxml)
ET.dump(newxml)
```

I'm reading from a variable and dumpin it on screen.

You can change it read from file and dump it to a file like you need.