# Python parsing weird root - TTML (XML) with ElementTree or lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml, elementtree, ttml

Here is a shortened example of the TTML file, which looks to me just like a specially formatted XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?> 
<tt xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml" xmlns:nttm="http://www.netflix.com/ns/ttml#metadata" xmlns:ttp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml#parameter" xmlns:tts="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml#styling" ttp:timeBase="media" ttp:version="2" tts:extent="1280px 720px" xml:lang="zh-Hans">
    <head>
        <metadata nttm:movieId="81170257" nttm:packageId="1618461" nttm:schemaVersion="0" nttm:textType="SUBS" nttm:uuid="9c50201b-f11e-4665-9944-3bda07268f29"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div begin="00:00:06.833" end="00:00:09.958" tts:extent="479px 51px" tts:origin="407px 597px">
            <image src="1.png"/>
        </div>
        <div begin="00:00:26.083" end="00:00:29.250" tts:extent="431px 46px" tts:origin="431px 602px">
            <image src="2.png"/>
        </div>
        <div begin="00:14:27.125" end="00:14:27.958" tts:extent="161px 46px" tts:origin="566px 602px">
            <image src="165.png"/>
        </div>
    </body> 
</tt>
```

Here is the code that I am running:

```
import lxml.etree as ET
tree = ET.parse("sample_ttml2.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
print(root.tag)
for div in root.iterfind(".//div"):
    print(div)
for div in root.iterfind("div"):
    print(div)
```

This outputs:

```
{http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml}tt
```

What I was expecting was the tt tag, without this namespace thing. When I attempt to iterate through, I get nothing, even when using an XPath. I think there is some problem with parsing it, but I have no idea why. Will I have to write my own parser?

Comment: The elements are namespaced; the `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml"` attribute tells the parser that the `tt` element belongs to the `http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml` namespace. Namespace declarations apply to the current element and *all children in the tree*, unless they have their own namespace declaration. See the [LXML documentation on namespaces and XPath](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#namespaces-and-prefixes).

Comment: I've found you the canonical duplicate for this problem, go see the answers to [how do I use empty namespaces in an lxml xpath query?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8053568)