# How to combine None and "g" namespace?

Tags: python, xpath, namespaces, lxml

I'm parsing Google products XML file that has "g" and also empty namespace.

```
<feed ...
    <entry>
        <g:id>2</g:id>
        <title>Some product
```

Trying to use `namespaces` attribute while getting `xpath`:

```
tree.xpath('/feed/entry/g:title',namespaces:{'': 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom', 'g': 'http://base.google.com/ns/1.0'})
```

which returns

```
empty namespace prefix is not supported in XPath
```

how to use the empty namespace?

Comment: Can you edit your question and show a short, well formed, representative sample of the xml?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how do I use empty namespaces in an lxml xpath query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053568/how-do-i-use-empty-namespaces-in-an-lxml-xpath-query)

Comment: Also—the [lxml documentation](https://lxml.de/dev/xpathxslt.html#namespaces-and-prefixes) says that XPath does not support default namespaces. Hence, the approach taken in the accepted answer to the question linked is necessary.

Comment: I suspect those elements are not truly in an empty namespace. Could you post the entirety of the outermost `<feed ...>` element?

Answer (score 0):

The important thing to remember is that the namespace prefix is merely an arbitrary prefix. It's not required to be empty, and you can make it anything you want.

From context, I'm assuming this is what your XML looks like?

If so, the elements without a prefix are not in an empty namespace. They're in the `http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom` namespace, and you need only assign it an arbitrary prefix in your function call.

```
In [1]: from lxml import etree

In [2]: string = '''
   ...: <feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
   ...:     <entry>
   ...:         <g:id>2</g:id>
   ...:         <title>Some product</title>
   ...:     </entry>
   ...: </feed>
   ...: '''

In [3]: root = etree.fromstring(string)

In [4]: root.xpath('/foo:feed/foo:entry/foo:title',namespaces={'foo': 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom', 'bar': 'http:/
   ...: /base.google.com/ns/1.0'})
Out[4]: [<Element {http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}title at 0x10a3d7d40>]

In [5]: root.xpath('/foo:feed/foo:entry/bar:id',namespaces={'foo': 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom', 'bar': 'http://b
    ...: ase.google.com/ns/1.0'})
Out[5]: [<Element {http://base.google.com/ns/1.0}id at 0x10a9ed4c0>]
```