# lxml XPath returns empty list

Tags: python-3.x, xml, xpath, lxml

I am trying to parse the XML below and read its content. The XML in is bytes. All XPath queries return empty.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Invoice
    xmlns="urn:eslog:2.00"
    xmlns:in="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.1.1#"
    xmlns:io="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
    xmlns:xs4xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:eslog:2.00 eSLOG20_INVOIC_v200.xsd">
    <M_INVOIC Id="data">
        <S_UNH>
            <D_0062>1889</D_0062>
            <C_S009>
                <D_0065>INVOIC</D_0065>
                <D_0052>D</D_0052>
                <D_0054>01B</D_0054>
                <D_0051>UN</D_0051>
            </C_S009>
        </S_UNH>
        <S_BGM>
            <C_C002>
                <D_1001>380</D_1001>
            </C_C002>
            <C_C106>
                <D_1004>1889</D_1004>
            </C_C106>
        </S_BGM>
    </M_INVOIC>
</Invoice>
```

Below is the code I tried with output in the comments. `.fromstring()` seem to work, since it returns something, but XPath queries return empty list. Your help is much appreciated.

```
def load(self, file):

        # print(file)  # b'<?xml version="1.0" ...
        # print(type(file))  # <class 'bytes'>

        root = etree.parse(BytesIO(file))
        # print(root.tag)  # Returns: object has no attribute 'tag'
        print(root.xpath('/Invoice'))  # Returns: []
        # print(root.nsmap)  # object has no attribute 'nsmap'

        root = etree.fromstring(file)
        print(root.tag)  # {urn:eslog:2.00}Invoice
        # print(root.xpath('/Invoice'))  # []
        # print(root.xpath('/{urn:eslog:2.00}Invoice')) # Invalid expression
        print(root.nsmap)  # {None: 'urn:eslog:2.00', 'in': ...
        print(root.xpath('/Invoce/M_INVOIC', nsmap = root.nsmap[None]))  # [] for all dict keys
        ns = { # a copy of root.nsmap
            'None': 'urn:eslog:2.00',
            'in': 'http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.1.1#',
            'io': 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#',
            'xs4xs': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema',
            'xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'}
        print(root.xpath('/Invoice/M_INVOIC/S_BGM/C_C106/D_1004', namespaces=ns)) # empty []
        print(root.xpath('/in:Invoice/M_INVOIC/S_BGM/C_C106/D_1004', namespaces=ns)) # empty []
        print(root.xpath('/io:Invoice/M_INVOIC/S_BGM/C_C106/D_1004', namespaces=ns)) # empty []
        print(root.xpath('/xs4xs:Invoice/M_INVOIC/S_BGM/C_C106/D_1004', namespaces=ns)) # empty []
        print(root.xpath('/xsi:Invoice/M_INVOIC/S_BGM/C_C106/D_1004', namespaces=ns)) # empty []
```

Comment: You need to take the default namespace (declared by `xmlns="urn:eslog:2.00"`) into account. https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#namespaces-and-prefixes

Comment: Very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/8056239/407651

Comment: @mzjn I tried to add namespaces (also updated the question above), but the result is the same. Is there something I am not seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The names of the elements in your XML document *all* belong to the namespace whose name is `urn:eslog:2.00`. That's because that namespace is declared as the "default" namespace (i.e. without a prefix), and none of the element names use a prefix.

Apart from the `urn:eslog:2.00` namespace, there are 3 other namespace URIs bound to the prefixes `in`, `io`, and `xs4xs`, but those prefixes are not used anywhere in the document, so they are irrelevant.

The `xs` prefix is only used in the `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute of the root element, but none of your XPath expressions refer to that attribute.

So in your `ns` namespace map that defines the binding of namespace prefixes and URIs, I think you only need to declare a single namespace (i.e. the `urn:eslog:2.00` namespace), and then use the prefix you've associated with that URI in your XPath expressions.

Currently you have bound that namespace URI to the prefix `None`, but your XPaths don't use the `None` prefix in any of elements it names. I think if you changed your XPaths to use that prefix then they should work, e.g.

```xml
/None:Invoice/None:M_INVOIC/None:S_BGM/None:C_C106/None:D_1004
```

Of course a better prefix than `None` would be e.g. `eslog`, but the prefix you choose is arbitrary: it's the namespace URI that matters; your XPaths need to use a prefix that's bound to that URI.